# Upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.2 using Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

I want to upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.2. When I go to the Magento Connect Manager, nothing shows up under Manage Existing Extension. I have verified all files and directories are writable. I am new to Magento and this will be the first time I have upgraded. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default the connect manager is used to upgrade 3rd party extensions and not core magento. My Advice would be to not to it on a live environment. I would suggest creating a staging/dev environment where you can preform the upgrade by extrating the zip of the magento version found on https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ into the folder where you magento folder is installed. Again Make sure this is done on a staging/dev environment so that no errors will appear in your live environment.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html#upgrade-ee-versions

Then you can test the site and find any issues before they appear on your live environment and impact sales.